# How to create data frame with duplicated column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to create a data frame with the same name. Using the standard approach:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(data={
    'colName': [1],
    'colName': [2]
   })
```

i get

```
   colName
0        2
```

instead of

```
   colName colName
0        1       2
```

Do you have any idea how to create excepted data frame? It is required fot Unit Tests.

Comment: a dictionary cannot have multiple keys of same name. Also duplicate column names would lead to some troubles in further operations with pandas.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be:

```
In [452]: df=pd.DataFrame(data={
     ...:     'colName1': [1],
     ...:     'colName2': [2]
     ...:    })

In [453]: df
Out[453]: 
   colName1  colName2
0         1         2

In [454]: df.columns = ['colName', 'colName']

In [455]: df
Out[455]: 
   colName  colName
0        1        2
```

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionary automatically overrides duplicate keys. So

```
{
'colName': [1],
'colName': [2]
}
```

is actually just one key. One way to go is:

```
# row wise 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
# or column wise
# df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,3,5], 1:[2,4,6]})

df.columns = ['colName', 'colName']
```

However, I should not that duplicate column names are discourage in Pandas.